# How to enable Keep-Alive in Apache-Nginx configured webserver [ DirectAdmin ]

Tags: keep-alive

i dont know what to say ive searched every where to enable keep-alive on nginx but nothing ,

is there any one to tell me step by step enable it?

webserver: nginx-apache [ custom-build 2 [DirectAdmin] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should increase the timeout of keep-alive in configuration.